# Visual Studio Code unusually slow

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am using an i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.8GHz. However, after I installed visual studio code and set its C++ compiler from the visual studio community 2019, I got a very slow performance even running the simple program hello world.

It took me 1 minute to compile and 2 minutes to run the program.
For instance, when I typed cl test.cpp, I have to wait 1 minute for it to finish compiling. Then I would type test.exe, another 2 minutes.

Here is my hello world program stored on the desktop.

---

```
#include <iostream> 
void main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

---

Then for a 60 line program, I will have to wait 4 minutes for it to compile and even longer to run. I find it very unusual, please let me know if there is any bug or problem in the program. Or if there are any solutions to this problem.

My process explorer image:
[image: My process explorer image]

PE while running the program:
[image: PE while running the program]

Comment: Check your task manager to see if any other application is taking up a lot of memory/processing time on your computer.

Comment: Damn peculiar. What he said ^ except use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).Might be an overzealous antivirus scanner.

Comment: For a test, see what happens if you run the Visual Studio compiler from Visual Studio.

Comment: I don't see any application taking too much memory...

Comment: Nor anything significant consuming CPU. Can't see the compiler running, in fact. Try to get a snapshot of the system while it is compiling that little file.

Comment: When I typed my code in visual studio, it is much faster.
Only when compiling in visual studio code, it is slow.

Comment: My first guess would be anti virus

Comment: !!!!! Thanks Alan! When I turned off my anti-virus, it suddenly runs!!

Comment: Now we found the problem... I will then need to find out how to let the program pass through without the interference of the anti-virus!
I am using F-secure!

Comment: I recommend using Microsoft Defender as your antivirus protection.  It is quite robust, and Microsoft has strong incentive to have it perform well.

Comment: @Willy add the directories of your project to the excluded directories:  https://community.f-secure.com/t5/F-Secure-SAFE/How-do-I-exclude-a-file-or/ta-p/56363

Comment: Amazing! Now I could code much faster! Thanks!

Comment: The question is clear and concise. [mcve] is given. The OP showed effort to solve the problem. It's not directly related to C++ but it is (indirectly), and it's a common problem which may occur to other C++ developers as well (entry level or not). I find it worth to be archived - would enjoy it earns some upvotes. The OP might provide a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) which he may accept (later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From other users' comments, I've finalised the problem to be F-secure security software interfering with VSC.

Tried unloading it has reduced the compile and run time significantly.
However, the exclusion list method does not work as well as unloading. 
There might be another solution after I've asked the official F-secure support team!

Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score -1):

I have a mcafee antivirus, though in my case it was 20 seconds of compile time for a `Hello world` program. I disabled antivirus realtime scanning and now its taking 0.5 seconds. Hope this may help someone.

Answer (score -1):

I have discovered that windows defender is also causing this problem, disabling its realtime scanning can solve this problem. This might be a cause if anti-virus softwares are not installed.

I have found a possible solution to this problem, windows defender is affecting the compiled .exe file and caused the time wasting. So you need to alter your tasks.json and launch.json, change the path that save the compiled .exe file to a certain folder, then add the folder to the exception items of the anti-virus app. The problem will be solved. Also you can add a .bat file to delete the file in that folder when system boots up.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).